# How to connect to OData service with generated OData client?

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-crm

I generated the client code from a for OData V4 service (Dynamics 365 metadata) using the `OData V4 Client Code Generator` project template (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator).

The code was generated fine and it compiles. Now the problem is that I simply cannot find a way to make a connection (or context) that can be used when querying data (OData linq queries for example).

All the examples I've read basically just "start right away" with having a Context or a Resource available, but none of them actually specify why or how it's there.

For example https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2014/03/11/tutorial-sample-how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class/ shows how to generate the classes and then creates an instance of `NorthwindEntities` (or `XxxxEntities`) which, again, I don't have generated (I don't have anything named "Entities" in the generated code).

https://stoneridgesoftware.com/working-with-the-odata-endpoint-in-dynamics-365-for-operations/ just simply creates a new instance of `Resources` class, which I don't have (what is it?). I have nothing named Resources in the generated code.

Obviously it can't be this difficult so maybe I'm missing something.

EDIT: the generated class contains only classes `Crmbaseentity`, `CrmbaseentitySingle`, `ExtensionMethods` and then the entity classes themselves. There simply are no other classes.

Any ideas how to do this differently or any blog posts that I've missed?

Comment: Is there something like `public partial class Container : global::Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext` in your generated code? Maybe a different name, but the base class is important. I think in the Northwind example it's NorthwindEntities.

Comment: No there isn't any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the code generation template from https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration/tree/master/ServiceSamples/ODataUtility. When I added the OData service to the project as a "service refernce" and used the wizard, then the code was generated normally.

I still don't know the actual reason why the T4 template didn't work.